# Devise Registration controller/page behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

1. Is there a way to avoid :require_no_authentication callback to be called?

- Adding **before_action :authenticate_user!** in the controller does nothing. I guess its because of the **:require_no_authentication** in Devise source code that is being prepended to the callback chain.

2. When signed in, can we change the behavior and actually access the registration page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to access the registration page when you're already signed in?

Comment: The intention is to create new users, and not be available to everyone to sign up. Like Devise Invitable. Doing by hand using devise confirmable module. No need to much implementation in Devise, just some logic in devise controller and user model.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to do. You can just create your own controller to override the behaviour:

In `app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb`:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_action :require_no_authentication
end
```

In `routes.rb` you need to specify to Devise to use your controller:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  registrations: "users/registrations"
}
```

I've made some assumptions about your Devise setup, but this should give you the general idea.

Comment: Thanks Jon, what worked for me was: prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: :none